# Variable inside a command variable on bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sh

I'm trying to extract reference numbers for ip addresses which are not updated using BASH on centos, I have a CSV with not updated addresses (IPs_withoutrefn.csv) where I extract the second column, and then we compare this value against another CSV (IP-references.csv) to extract the reference number.

For this I was trying to do a variable in this way, but the output is always empty, if I try this command on shell without using a variable its working properly.

```
REFNO=$(grep "$IP" ../IP-references.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{sub(/\r$/,"");print $2"\r"}')
```

I already tried to convert this grep in a function, and to change the "$IP" inside the grep on different ways I read around here like ("^$IP;" or "$IP;" or ${IP} ... ) but the result its always same.

And this is the full code I'm using.

```
while IFS=";" read -r col1 col2

do

  #IP to variable#

        IP=$col2

        echo "$IP"

  #We search the IP and we extract the REFNO##

        REFNO=$(grep "$IP" ../IP-references.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{sub(/\r$/,"");print $2"\r"}')

        echo "$REFNO"

        echo "$IP"

done < "../IPs_withoutrefn.csv"
```

I hope its clearly enough for understanding, if not, please let me now.

IPs_withoutrefn.csv sample:

> - ;1.1.1.1
> - ;
> - ;1.1.1.2

IP-references.csv sample

> Client1;89345013745;modelno;status;node1;sect1;node2;sect2;;1.1.1.1;1.1.1.1;;;datexpiration;
>
> Client2;89345013746;modelno;status;node1;sect1;node2;sect2;;1.1.1.2;1.1.1.2;;;datexpiration;
>
> Client3;89345013747;modelno;status;node1;sect1;node2;sect2;;1.1.1.3;1.1.1.3;;;datexpiration;

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide some input ?

Comment: question updated with input references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut -d ";" -f 2 IPs_withoutrefn.csv  | xargs -I {} grep {} IP-references.csv`

This would print all lines in IP-references that match IP adresses from the first file.

You can further improve the output by adding `| cut -d ";" -f 1,11` to list in format

```
cut -d ";" -f 2 IPs_withoutrefn.csv  | xargs -I {} grep {} IP-references.csv | cut -d ";" -f 1,11
```

> Client1;1.1.1.1
>
> Client2;1.1.1.2

-d is for delimiter, -f for filed numbers

Comment: Hi, your solutions works very well, just i dont know why its not working with my original csv files, do you have any idea what this can be? my IP-references.csv file has many special characters like "#" "_" "-" "()" "/\" "&", i also tryed to add this characters on the sample files and its also working well. just not working with my original files.

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind: try replacing {} with something else (any weird string would do):
`cut -d ";" -f 2 IPs_withoutrefn.csv  | xargs -I @@@ grep @@@ IP-references.csv | cut -d ";" -f 1,11`
Also try  `fgrep` instead of `grep` - it is "literal" grep that treats every character as is without giving it special meaning. 
Which part of toolchain fails? First cut? Second grep?

Comment: `grep -e {}` is going to be more consistently well-behaved than `grep {}` -- without the `-e`, a string that starts as a dash could be treated as an option to `grep` rather than a string to match.